# Include warning on php

Tags: php, include, warnings

I have uploaded my web site on a server and then all the includes stop working.
 when i open the site this warning pops up:

> Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/showcaze/User/User.php) is not within
>   the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in
>   /home/a8739766/public_html/showcaze/login.php on line 3

line 3 is :

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/showcaze/User/User.php';
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Did you do a search on SO on "open_basedir restriction in effect" ? what did you try to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The open_base_dir setting is primarily used to prevent php scripts for a particular user from accessing files in another user's account. So usually, any files in your own account should be readable by your own scripts.

If you are on shared hosting, you are out of luck. If you have your own server or are on VPS then modify the open_basedir settings on your httpd configuration file.

Or .. you are using a wrong include and you are have no intententions to access a file outside   the basedir. You should, off course, adjust your include.